# iPhone Programming - NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, uitableview, indexing, nsmutablearray

***Hello folks!***

Could you tell me a **good(non-redundant)** way to find out the following:

**- If an object exists in a NSMutableArray

- How many times does the same object appear in the NSMutableArray

- and How to grab the index of each occurrence of that same object**

Is it possible to change the *cell.accessorytype* property for the indexes referred to above?

**Note:** I am parsing a JSON and display the data into a tableview*(Successfully completed).* But there is a boolean value in the JSON which represents if the *cell.accessorytype* will be null or something else. So I just want to grab the indexes where the boolean value is yes in the array, and thus change the *cell.accessorytype* property for these indexes.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this instance method of NSArray

-(NSIndexSet *)indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:(BOOL (^)(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop))predicate

Also for setting accessory types, in your cellForRow method, check if the index of cell matches with one of the returned index and set the type. When ever your data changes reload the table